# Sort subdictionary lists by their dictionary's key values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have an XML file(~500 lines), that is converted to nested ordered dictionary in Python. I need that to be sorted according to values, but because it is nested so much and has lists in it, I am lost. I have searched for answers, trying to find a way to sort dictionary that is mixed with lists. But no luck so far.

This is the closest I have got.  [Python: Sort nested dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575139/python-sort-nested-dictionary-by-value) But because I have a key that has 2 subkeys "foo" and "bar", which have lists, which themselves have dictionaries inside, it isn't not quite what I need.

I would like to sort "foo" and "bar" according to "Date".  Or return subdictionaries by "Date" values.

I have a loop that iterates through the subdictionary's list, but it does not sort it. I have tried changing it to fix it, but no changes. It also doesn't help, that lambda seems like magic to me.

```
for i in range(len(your_dict['History']['foo'])):
    mine = OrderedDict(sorted(your_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["foo"][i]['Date']))
```

Short example of the dictionary at hand:

```
"History": {
    "@version": "4.0",
    "foo": [
        {"code": "ID", "Date": "2018-07-09T15:31:09+03:00"},
        {"Date": "2018-07-09T13:46:09+03:00"}
    ],
    "bar": [
        {"code": "ID", "Date": "2018-07-09T09:39:29+03:00"},
        {"code": "ID", "Date": "2018-07-09T09:48:25+03:00"}
    ]
}
```

So how could "foo" and "bar" be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s = dict((k,sorted(v, key=lambda x: x['Date'])) for k,v in d['History'].items() if type(v)==list)
>>> s['foo']
[{'Date': '2018-07-09T13:46:09+03:00'}, {'code': 'ID', 'Date': '2018-07-09T15:31:09+03:00'}]
>>> s['bar']
[{'code': 'ID', 'Date': '2018-07-09T09:39:29+03:00'}, {'code': 'ID', 'Date': '2018-07-09T09:48:25+03:00'}]
```

**Explanation**
    The following list comprehension would return the dict items as key-value pairs

```
[(k,v) for k,v in d['History'].items()]
```

This would filter the key-value pairs and include them only when value is of type list

```
[(k,v) for k,v in d['History'].items() if type(v)==list]
# [('foo', [{'code': 'ID', 'Date': '2018-07-09T15:31:09+03:00'}, {'Date': '2018-07-09T13:46:09+03:00'}]), ('bar', [{'code': 'ID', 'Date': '2018-07-09T09:39:29+03:00'}, {'code': 'ID', 'Date': '2018-07-09T09:48:25+03:00'}])]
```

All we have to do now, is to sort each value based on date. `sorted(v, key=lambda x: x['Date']))`  would do that

Merging these in a single line, you get the above mentioned one-liner

Comment: Thank you, all in one line and exactly what I was hoping to do!  Could you explain the logic behind it?

Comment: Added some explanation

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I kinda at least know, what I am doing :D

Answer (score 0):

Using `sorted` with `lambda`

**Ex:**

```
d = {"History": {
    "@version": "4.0",
    "foo": [
        {"code": "ID", "Date": "2018-07-09T15:31:09+03:00"},
        {"Date": "2018-07-09T13:46:09+03:00"}
    ],
    "bar": [
        {"code": "ID", "Date": "2018-07-09T09:39:29+03:00"},
        {"code": "ID", "Date": "2018-07-09T09:48:25+03:00"}
    ]
    }
}
print(sorted(d["History"]["foo"], key=lambda k: k['Date']))
print(sorted(d["History"]["bar"], key=lambda k: k['Date']))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Date': '2018-07-09T13:46:09+03:00'}, {'Date': '2018-07-09T15:31:09+03:00', 'code': 'ID'}]
[{'Date': '2018-07-09T09:39:29+03:00', 'code': 'ID'}, {'Date': '2018-07-09T09:48:25+03:00', 'code': 'ID'}]
```

Comment: Could the result be saved as a variable? Like OrderedDict? Because I would need it later to make a summary of all the data.

Comment: You are sorting a list and not a dictionary...so I dnt think you need `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to get .items, while you just want to sort a list, so no need for all that stuff, just get it straightforward like this:

```
for i in ('foo', 'bar'):
   your_dict['History'][i] = sorted(your_dict['History][i], key=lambda x:x['date'])
```

Comment: Yeah, because it otherwise throws a _TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str_ Changing `History` to 1 works and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @veteran007 btw, because I don’t have enough rep, I can’t comment, but sunitha answer would fail if you would have other categories that contain list but that are not the correct data. But if you keep it your dict like that, there’s no problem.

Comment: Yeah, the original XML file is a system report, so the format of my dict won't change